# Bootstrap 3 carousel code

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I need to create Bootstrap 3 carousel, it needs to have image on the right side of the slide and text on the left side of the slide, but I simply can not make it, whatever code i tried it either bugged or didn't worked.

Tried this:

```
  <div class="carousel slide" id="myC">
    <div class="carousel inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h3>TEXT</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" alt=""/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h3>TEXT</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" alt=""/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h3>TEXT</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" alt=""/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And it didnot worked. I need something like this http://www.dodaj.rs/f/18/29/4TNTTm5d/untitled.png

Comment: Where is your try? and code ? Make an example on bootply and maybe add a screenshot of the desire output...... Show some effort.

Comment: as Danko said you need to show a bit more effort and also post your code ask a more precise question like: how to move a block left to right. And also before you pots search. I can find 5 different types of carousels easily. Even from there website:  http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

Comment: How can I download some of that templates?

Comment: @VladimirJovanovic You can simply copy the code in the source code, as Bootstrap only consists of HTML, CSS and JS.

Comment: Basically something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pwgjsrxk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what was problem, it seems that my .item class was pretty messed up, i fixed it and it worked.